# Holder inequality for integrals

Tags: holder-inequality

Using Holder inequality, is it correct to express $$\parallel \int\limits_0^t f(s)g(s)ds \parallel ^p \leq T^{p-1}\int \limits_0^t\parallel f(s)\parallel^pds\int \limits_0^t\parallel g(s)\parallel^pds $$

Answer (score 1):

No. Take $f(s)=g(s)=1$, $p=1$ and $t=1/2$.

Comment: Then how to express $$\parallel \int\limits_0^t f(s)g(s)ds \parallel ^p $$ as $$ \int \limits_0^t\parallel f(s)\parallel^pds\int \limits_0^t\parallel g(s)\parallel^p ds $$